Does NATO have its own "terrorist organization" and "state sponsor of terrorism" designations
The question is motivated by the report about Hamas shifting its headquarters to  Istanbul, Turkey. In the same time, Hamas is considered a terrorist organization by many NATO members, including the US (it is also designated as such by the EU, of which many NATO states are members.)
Related report by Reuters:
Turkey's Erdogan says he does not believe Hamas will leave Qatar

Is that report trustworthy? I had heard some noise about Qatar not being particularly happy with Hamas's presence, and obviously the Gaza Strip is not a tenable location, but I would think that on Hamas's side, they would be worried that a NATO member could easily be pressured by other members to arrest and extradite Hamas members. On Turkey's side, I would expect Erdogan would be worried about the possibility that Hamas would get it into their head to carry out an attack in the EU, particularly Germany, Turkey's main export partner, with negative consequences for the economy.

Not to mention that Erdogan has historically had some issues with religious Muslim political organizations, so I might also expect him to be concerned about Hamas being a threat to his authority.

@Obie2.0 Erdogan has long history of taking rather extreme side of the Palestinian cause, and his relations with Hamas are not new. Also, he has issues with some Muslim political organizations, but he and his party are also somewhat of religious conservatives.

I think this is an interesting question and deserves to be reopened. I have removed most of the content related to Hamas and Turkey, as it seems to be the reason for the downvotes and the closure. @FourLegsGoodTwoLegsBad feel free to revert this if it deviates too much from what you want to ask.

@Alexei: IDK if leaving just the initial, later denied by Erdogan report is a good move. I suspect the Q was closed because of that, but I'm not one of those who voted to close. The OP might want to ask on meta. I've also heard from al-Jazeera that Turkey was [just] substituting Qatar as an intermediary in the negotiations between Hamas and Israel... but that doesn't seem to be confirmed by Erdogan either. Only that Qatar was annoyed at the criticism directed at them and was 'stepping back'. But in the end it, even that might not have happened.

@thegodsfromengineering I also removed that paragraph initially, but that would have invalidated (or at least strange) the second paragraph of your answer.

Now I can't find the al-Jazeera piece, so maybe it was changed/retracted. Other sources like CNBC say only that Qatar 're-evaluates' its role.

@Alexei: I think 2nd story/report (which was also added by the OP) that cast doubt on the 1st  should have been kept though. It should be enough to mollify those who objected to the question as reporting fake/unreliable news.

@thegodsfromengineering I added the second story to the question since I couldn't post it as an answer (the Q. was closed.) Feel free to incorporate it in yours - I think it belongs to this thread. Also, the very first comment above expressed doubt in the credibility of the report.

Looks reasonable the way it is now. I my experience, criticizing the close votes in the Q rarely helps.

Most likely, no. There's a NATO page detailing what counter-terrorism activities they do, but maintaining any lists isn't mentioned.
Even if they have one somehow, it's not binding since Turkey doesn't consider Hamas a terror organization. (Conversely, Turkey lists the US-backed YPG as terrorists, but the EU doesn't etc.)
